# chrome.extension undefined, Javascript doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, undefined

I have a Javascript code which checks which browser the user has, the code:

```
var xmlHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1) { // Chrome
    alert(chrome); // alerts "[object Object]"
    alert(chrome.extension); // alerts "undefined"
    xmlHR.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL(path), true);
} else {
    // do stuff
}
```

chrome.extension is undefined.

I didn't include any Chrome related scripts to the .js , what's needed to be done to have 'extension' defined ?

Comment: what does `console.log(chrome)` print?

Comment: Object {loadTimes: function, csi: function, app: Object, webstore: Object}
app: Object
csi: function () { native function GetCSI(); return GetCSI();}
loadTimes: function () { native function GetLoadTimes(); return GetLoadTimes();}
webstore: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: So you are trying to access chrome extension features without creating an extension?

Comment: Hmm I'm just trying to access the URL (path), but I didn't know I need to create anything, is there a simple code that does just that ? I can't find anything online

Answer (score 0):

The chrome.extension API (and most other chrome.* APIs relating to extensions) is only defined a chrome extensions, not for the open web.  If you want to write a chrome extension, then there are a few good tutorials around https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.

The method you mention (chrome.extension.getURL()) is used to reference an extension's resources - if you are trying to do that for a normal website, then it will depend on your configuration, but likely it would be easiest to query the server for the resource at the path.

Hope that helps. :)